# Adding inputs that have a mask on them?

Tags: jquery, maskedinput

How do I add the input values with parsefloat if the input also has a jquery mask attached to it?

I am using jquery maskMoney to give my input 2 decimal places and a $ for the value (i.e. $ 410.00), but if say I had 4 inputs in a column and a total input, I believe I get NaN when I try to add the inputs.

The js file I am using is [here](http://plentz.github.io/jquery-maskmoney/) or if there is any way to mask an input with a $ and two decimal places and a comma for the thousands (i.e. $ 1,233.00)   and can add them up that is all I am looking for.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: You should add a minimal code example to your question (not using a link).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have this plugin available to test but from the link you included it appears you can do something like this.

```
<input type="text" id="val1">
<input type="text" id="val2">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#val1').maskMoney();
    $('#val2').maskMoney();
    var result = $('#val1').maskMoney('unmasked')[0] + $('#val2').maskMoney('unmasked')[0]
</script>
```

Comment: Could you give me a sample of how you would attach this to the whole script? Maybe just the general html and js please. I'm sorry but kinda confused with the 2 demo 8 id's? Are they supposed to be classes i.e. .demo8 ? Thank you so much :-)